# Vue обработка событий

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Не пойму что не так.. постараюсь как можно подробнее объяснить. Есть обработчик событий, который отправляет запрос на сервер, чтобы верифицировать код, который пришел на почту пользователю. Проблема в том, что он отрабатывает только один раз. Если код указан неверно, обработчик просто перестает работать (ставил вывод в консоль, ничего не выводил, в нетворках тоже ничего нет). При этом никаких атрибутов disabled И так далее кнопке не проставляется (ни кодом не предусмотрено, и в «показать код элемента» тоже ничего нет) отсюда вывод напрашивается, что обработчик отрабатывает только один раз, на последующих же кликах никак вообще. У кого то может такая проблема была? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А модификатора .once у события случайно нет?

Comment: .once нет, но есть .prevent, но он есть почти на всех, и все отрабатывают норм

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была не в самом обработчике, а в глобальных переменных, которые ставили условия в нем (в обработчике был вложен другой метод) так что это я тупанул, не проверил сразу..

Comment: На будущее. Чтобы Вам смогли ответить, публикуйте код. Почитайте про это в справке https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask